# Element is already the child of another element

Tags: silverlight-4.0

```
for( i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  MyDockPanel.Children.Add( MyFrameWorkElement);
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

> Element is already the child of
>   another element.

How can I add the same element multiple times in Silverlight?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a single instance of a framework element to multiple parents.  You need to create several instances.  For example:

```
for( i=0; i<10; i++) { MyDockPanel.Children.Add( new MyFrameWorkElement()); }
```

More likely, you would include code within your loop to first create each new instance, set some properties on it, then add it to the parent.

Good luck!

Comment: MyFraneworkElement contain control which assign using property. If I do new it will initialize again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to create new instances of `MyFrameWorkElement`. Right now you are trying to add the *same instance* multiple times. It is not clear what that object is, but try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  MyDockPanel.Children.Add(new MyFrameWorkElement());
}
```

Comment: MyFraneworkElement contain control which assign using property. If I do new it will initialize again.

Comment: @Anthony: aye. Moved. @user737720: if the above code does not work for your setup, please update your original post. Add the property or code segment which makes it fail.